# Font Awesome 5 use social/brand icons in React

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

The Font Awesome documentation shows only how to add regular/solid fonts to React. How about social icons?

First I grabbed the packages:

```
  npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core \
  npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons \
  npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Note: I replaced `npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons \` with `npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons \`

Then in React:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faFacebookF } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons' 

library.add(faFacebookF);
```

And tried using a component:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-facebook-f" />
```

even tried:

and keep getting in the console

> Could not find icon {prefix: "fas", iconName:
>   "fa-facebook-f"}

I believe I somehow have to get the `fab` prefix for brands.

This is the icon I want to use https://fontawesome.com/icons/facebook-f?style=brands

Comment: Have you tried just `<FontAwesomeIcon icon="facebook" />`?

Comment: I get `Could not find icon {prefix: "fas", iconName: "facebook"}`

Comment: Have you tried just <FontAwesomeIcon icon="facebook-f" /> or <FontAwesomeIcon icon="facebookF" />

Comment: Yes I tried that too

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'facebook-f']} />
```

Note that font awesome now has different icon sets. The solid set (`fas`) is the default. The facebook icon is in the brands set (`fab`).

Comment: Why do you have to add `-f`? (It doesn't work.)

Comment: @RichardBarraclough This answer is now four and a half years old. Unsurprisingly the API has changed in that time. To see the current way of doing things, please go to the following page and click the React tab. https://fontawesome.com/icons/facebook-f?s=solid&f=brands

Answer (score 55):

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome"
import { faFacebook } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons"

const icon = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} />
```

I found the spelling/casing of the brand icons on [FontAwesome's GitHub](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/1975bba5c4ade236c02bf2e5f9551160ee85109d/js-packages/%40fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons)

Answer (score 11):

Note that you **must** run the commands that you ran first:

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core 
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons 
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

I'd tried to import without installing first - and of course that didn't work.

Answer (score 8):

Install these dependencies first

```sh
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons 
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Create a custom library `initFontAwesome.js` and paste this code.

```js
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import {fab, faTwitterSquare, faFacebook, faLinkedin, faGithub} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";

function initFontAwesome() {
    library.add(fab, faTwitterSquare, faFacebook, faLinkedin, faGithub);
}
export default initFontAwesome;
```

In the `App.js` include the following code

```js
import initFontAwesome from "./initFontAwesome";
initFontAwesome();

function App() {
  return (

   {/*---------Some code----------*/}

  );
}
export default App;
```

In `Home.jsx` include the following code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

{/*-------some Code---------*/}

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'twitter']} />

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'facebook']} />

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'linkedin']} />

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'github']} />

{/*-------Some Code---------*/}

This worked for me. I hope this helps!
```

Answer (score 6):

Firstly

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core 
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons 
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Then import in your project

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {  faFacebookF , } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
```

Use this

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookF} />
```