# Fontawesome 5 React Brand Icons not working - how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome-5

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid';
import '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
```

In rendering code:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={'facebook'} />

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab','facebook']} />

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab','facebook-f']} />
```

Nothing works.
I have the following errors:

```
backend.js:6 Could not find icon {prefix: "fab", iconName: "facebook"} 
    in FontAwesomeIcon (created by MyView)
    in DashboardView (created by Router.Consumer)
    in Router.Consumer (created by Route)
    in Route
```

What am I missing?

I saw someone's advice to import specific objects like  -

```
import { faFacebookF } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
```

from here [Font Awesome 5 use social/brand icons in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52687229/font-awesome-5-use-social-brand-icons-in-react) (and it's not a duplicate).

But I don't want to import specific objects, because my users should be able to use any icons, and it's specified in the model.

It's also unclear how these icons all work.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the import to:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
```

and add the following code:

```
library.add(fab);
```

After these changes everything started working.